# DynamoDB: What might be the reason for TransactionInProgressException

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Using transactWriteItems from the aws-sdk(js) document client we get a TransactionInProgressException with the message: "Transaction from previous request is still in progress".
From the documentation for [TransactWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html)it only states:

> The transaction with the given request token is already in progress.

As far as I understand it the request token is unique for each TransactWriteItem, which is taken care of by document client. So given the fact this transaction was triggered once from the application what would be the root cause for this error?

Comment: Did you find the reason?

Comment: Hi @smaudi,  this is the reponse I've got from support: 
_Why it happened and how to resolve this issue? 

There was a previous request, which was timedout, and lamdba retried the request while the first request was not completed(in progress, it was).

During a transaction, the item to be modified is locked and that item is blocked from being mutated by any other process except the initial transaction. The initial transaction will have the lock and priority to retry the transaction in hopes of completing correctly._ I've just added a retry for cases, when this specific error occurs.

Comment: could you share your retry code?

Comment: @smaudi just the idea, basically using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#transactWrite-property - if the calling function receives err, I'm looking into err.code for conditions that can be retried.